# Can two equal classes be separated wrt an oracle?

Tags: complexity-theory, relativization

Is it known if there are two classes of languages $A$ and $B$ such that:

1. $A$ and $B$ are defined wrt the exact same type of machine (e.g. 1-tape Deterministic Turing Machines, 2-tape Deterministic Turing Machines, 1-tape Nondeterministic Turing Machines, etc);
2. neither $A$ or $B$ are defined wrt a restriction on space usage;
3. $A = B$;
4. there is an oracle $O$ for which $A^O \neq B^O$?

Comment: This question is very similar to a [previous question of mine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/88452/why-relativization-cant-solve-p-vs-np-example-request), but the additional condition that neither A or B should be defined wrt a restriction on space usage make the questions different. I had previously asked this question in cstheory, but by the downvotes I guess the question is not research level.

Comment: I don't understand. You have the same class of languages, somehow defined in different ways with respect to the same kind of Turing machine? Are you imagining something like A is "languages accepted by deterministic Turing machines in polynomial time" and B is "languages accepted by deterministic Turing machines that do XYZ" and it turns out that these are the same classes of languages? Can you give a concrete example of this?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I can give an example for a pair of languages that would satisfy points 1,2,4: $P$ and $NP$ (or $NP$ and $coNP$). Just recall that a language $L$ is in $NP$ if there is a certificate for each word $w \in L$ whose length is polynomial on the length of $w$, such that a Deterministic TM can check that $w \in L$ in polytime (wrt the length of the certificate).

Comment: P and NP aren't languages: they're classes of languages. It's also not clear that the verifier definition of NP is "the same machine model" as the model defining P, since the deterministic TM doesn't accept the NP language: you need to do a projection. Anyway, P and EXP are trivial examples of things satisfying 1, 2 and 4. Do you have any concrete examples satisfying 1, 2 and 3? Because it's not clear to me that your requirements make sense.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, indeed. Sorry, again that's what I meant (regarding the definition of NP).  Well, for 1,2,3 we have IP and IPP.

Comment: The question doesn't clearly define what it means for a class to be "defined wrt a type of machine" or for a class to be "defined wrt a restriction on space usage".  I don't think that's well-defined.  A language is a subset of $\{0,1\}^*$; a complexity class is a set of languages; it doesn't necessarily have to be defined in terms of any machine at all; and there are usually many ways to define any given complexity class (not always using the same notion of a "machine" in all cases).  So I just don't think the requirements are well-specified.

Comment: @D.W. Sorry that I didn't make it more clear. I'm aware that complexity classes aren't defined wrt a particular computation model; however, oracles are. I have a believe (or at least had) that certain models of computations could take way more advantage of having access to an oracle than others, and that, that fact doesn't render relativizinhg techniques completely bleak for proving the $P$ vs $NP$. The reason for disallowing $PSPACE$ is *Savitch's theorem*. Although I already had this idea before, the comments from Ryan O'Donnell and Ryan Williams reinforced it.

Comment: [their comments are here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35664/why-relativization-cant-solve-np-p?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This was probably already said, but without proper formalization, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Ariel, yes it was indeed. I'll formalize the question as soon as I find a way to do it. Should I delete the question meanwhile? (I didn't want to delete the comments already made to the question, though).

Comment: @GuilhermeRito The problem is that I don't think anyone here will be able to formalize this in a satisfactory manner. Categorizing different characterization of complexity classes is hard, as can be seen in the (at least for now) informal notion of semantic vs syntactic classes, and in this example we have a better intuition of whats going on. Thus, unfortunately, I find it hard to believe that someone will find a meaningful formalization of this.

Comment: @Ariel I'm trying to come up with a formal definition. But indeed I don't know if I'll manage to do it as I wanted to.

Comment: @Ariel Well, I think I gave it a decent shot at formalizing a part of it. The only important part that remains informal is the 'type' of a machine used to define a language class. Putting aside the difficulty to formalize that, I think the only one that has an idea of what it is supposed to mean currently is the one who asked of the question.

Answer (score 3):

While the other answer answers the question as posed (at least, given your definition of 'type of machine'), I still think the question is rather ill-posed and that resolving this is a solution as well.

### Problems with the current definition

First of all, as @D.W. mentioned in the comments, the claim 'Language class $X$ is defined w.r.t. machine $M$' is ill-posed. There is no need to define a class of languages with a machine at all. Even if we have a language which is commonly described w.r.t. some machine, such as $P$, there is nothing preventing us to give an equivalent definition that uses no machine at all! (Not sure if this is doable or has been done. Perhaps you can do something based on $\lambda$-calculus?)

The second problem is that oracle access is not a modifier/property of a language class! This follows immediately from the previous point: if I define a language without using a machine, how on earth am I able to use this oracle if I don't even have a machine?

The crucial mistake that leads to your problem is that a 'language' under oracle access actually depends on the definition of the language and a 'language' with oracle access is **not** invariant under the method you use to define the language. In fact, the often posed statement $P^O = NP^O$ is an example of *really bad notation*, as $P$ and $NP$ aren't actually languages here, but methods to define languages!

Let's make this precise: Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a 'definition method' for languages that can access oracles (for example, a set of machines and some acceptance rules) Let $L(\mathcal{X})$ be the language class that is defined by $\mathcal{X}$. Let $\mathcal{X}^O$ be the extension of $\mathcal{X}$ with access to the oracle $O$.

### Rephrasing the question

Your question can now be rephrased as follows, let language classes $A$, $B$ such that:

> 1. There exists an $\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y}$ such that $A= L(\mathcal{X})$, $B = L(\mathcal{Y})$ and $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are 'of the same type'.
> 2. $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are able to use unbounded space.
> 3. $A=B$
> 4. There exists an oracle $O$ such that $L(\mathcal{X}^O) \neq L(\mathcal{Y}^O)$

By combining 3 and 1, we can do without $A$, $B$ and focus on the machines:

> 1. $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are 'of the same type' and are able to use unbounded space.
> 2. There exists an oracle $O$ such that $L(\mathcal{X}^O) \neq L(\mathcal{Y}^O)$

Now, the question crucially depends on what 'the same type' means. If $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y}$, then satisfying both 1 and 2 becomes impossible, as  we now do have $\mathcal{X}^O = \mathcal{Y}^O$, so $L(\mathcal{X}^O) = L(\mathcal{Y}^O)$.

So, a necessary condition for statements 1 and 2 is the claim:

> There exists an oracle $O$ such that $\mathcal{X}^O \neq \mathcal{Y}^O$.

You can define 'type' however you wish, but if two machines don't behave the same when I give them the same oracle, I don't consider those machines to be of the same type.

So, in conclusion, after rephrasing your question more formally and giving a property which I believe 'type' should adhere to, the answer to your question is actually no.

Comment: You might disagree with my conclusion, but I hope formally modelling the question makes it clear what it is actually about and that in the end it depends on how the _machines_ behave, not the language classes.

Comment: The complexity class $\mathsf{P}^O$ consists of all languages accepted by polynomial time machines with access to an $O$-oracle, and $\mathsf{NP}^O$ can be defined in a similar fashion. These are well-defined complexity classes.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, they are well defined, but IMO written down badly. You explicitly use the _machine defining $P$_ to construct $P^O$ not the language class $P$.

Comment: This is standard notation. You might not like it, but it does appear in the literature.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, and it is precisely this 'standard notation' that is the source of OP's confusion. I can rephrase the 'more formal' bit into 'more clear', but I think my point stands.

Comment: @Discretelizard, thank you for your answer. It might've appeared (from my ill-posed question) that the only definition I know for $P$ is the one using TMs. I wanted to say that I actually know more (I'm familiar with recursion theoretic definitions of, for example, $FPSPACE$, and so I totally understand that $P$ can be defined without respect to a particular model of machine). But there is a reason why I asked to consider that $A$ and $B$ were defined (I should've written definable, actually [I'm sorry!]) wrt the same type of machine, and the reason why is in part what you say in your answer.

Comment: In addition, as Yuval Filmus mentions, it's standard notation. But note that, as [Ryan O'Donnel mentions here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35664/why-relativization-cant-solve-np-p?noredirect=1&lq=1) it's nevertheless ill-defined standard notation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Yes, I know that. That's why I said that the classes should be defined wrt the same type of machine (because oracles are defined wrt types of machines). But the question is still ill-defined, and I have to improve it. Although you answered it correctly, the question I really wanted to make was different, but before I make another question, I'll first think how to say exactly what I want to say.

Comment: @GuilhermeRito Sorry -- by "your version", I meant the version given in this answer. I agree that the concept you're looking for seems to be very hard to pin down, exactly. That's not a criticism, just an acceptance that you're trying to ask a subtle question where things that seem to make sense intuitively can be very hard to write down formally.

Comment: @DavidRicherby actually, although I said that the type of machines are the same for IP and IPP, they aren't. Here is why: when defining a type of machine, one should declare what it means for a machine of such type to accept or not a language. *However*, for IP and IPP, the conditions for a language to be accepted are different, even though the idea of the machine is the same. In my opinion the definition of IP and IPP is in this sense broken, in that the definition of the complexity class defines what it means for the PTM machine to accept the language or not.

Comment: @GuilhermeRito That's not broken at all. For example, **NP** and **co-NP** are defined by the same kind of machine (nondeterministic TM with polynomial time bound) and different acceptance criteria (for **NP**, accept if any path accepts; for **co-NP**, reject if any path rejects). If that's broken, complexity theory is an inherently broken subject.

Comment: @DavidRicherby $NP$ is defined as the class of languages such that: a language $L$ is in $NP$ if for each $w \in L$ there is a certificate such that a DTM can check, given $w$ and the certificate, that $w \in L$. On the other hand, $co-NP$ is defined as $co-NP = \{L : \overline{L} \in NP\}$. So the definition of $co-NP$ is totally independent from any type of machine.

Comment: @GuilhermeRito OK, I think you really need to clarify your thinking on this subject. Because, to me "the complement of a language accepted by an NTM running in poly time" is absolutely dependent on a type of machine. And, in any case, I just gave you an unambiguously machine-dependent alternative definition of **co-NP**.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't understand your comment. $\mathcal{X}$ is not a language class. I explicitly state it is a 'definition method' for languages, similar to what you describe

Comment: @DavidRicherby I (respectfully) disagree with you. $co-NP$ is defined wrt a type of machine iff $NP$ is. And $NP$ is not defined wrt a NTM, but instead wrt a DTM. [Sorry to repeat myself] A language $L$ is in $NP$ if there is a DTM $M$ st for each $w \in L$ there is a certificate $c$ st $M(w,c) = 1$ and for any $w \notin L$, there is no certificate $c$ s.t. $M(w,c) = 1$. [See [Arora and Barak's book, page 56 of 489](http://theory.cs.princeton.edu/complexity/book.pdf)]

Comment: @Discretelizard It looks like I misunderstood something -- sorry.

Comment: @GuilhermeRito There are many equivalent definitions of **NP**. For most people, the most natural one is in terms of NTMs running in polynomial time -- after all, that's how the class got it's name... Honestly, it's pretty ridiculous to insist that **NP** is not defined in terms of NTMs. Anyway, you've now claimed in your two most recent comments that "the definition of **co-NP** is totally independent from any type of machine" _and_ that it's defined in terms of Turing machines because **NP** is. I don't think there's anything more to discuss here. You're simply not making sense.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Yes, sorry, I contradicted myself.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Can $NP^O$ be understood in terms of the certificate-verifier characterization of $NP$? eg is it the same as the set of problems solvable in polynomial time by a DTM with access to both a 3SAT solution-providing oracle and $O$?